# Software Centre locked up

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Software Centre has locked up during install of krita. Problem seems to be corrupted download of krita-data. Can't remove or install anything and have followed onscreen instructions such as apt-get install -f but no good.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post the exact error message you see on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

On Terminal console try

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

post up error messages if any.

Comment: Tried that but still locked up.

Comment: The problem seems to be that if an install fails apt stops until it is installed and Synaptic is locked out. I'd be happy to be rid of my half-installed krita but I don't know how do that.

Comment: Found the answer. sudo dpkg -r krita followed by dpkg ---purge krita did the job and cleared Synaptic. All running smooth;y now. GC.